# The provided key element does not match the schema update_item dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hello guys this will be my first post here as I am learning how to code. When I try to update my table in Dynamodb using a lambda function I get the following error message. "The provided key element does not match the schema" my table name is correct and I am able to connect to it. My primary key is just a hash key which is id. its value is 1 so I do not see why it is giving me this error here.

```py
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Visitors')

def lambda_handler (event, context):

    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            "id": {"N":"1"}
            },
    ExpressionAttributeNames = { 
    "#c": "Counters"
    },
    UpdateExpression= "set #c = :val",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":val": {"N":"1"}
        }
       )
```

Comment: Confusingly, there are two update_item methods in the boto3 DynamoDB SDK: [client-level](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item) and [resource-level](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.update_item). As @jellycsc points out, you've created a resource (a dynamodb.Table) but are attempting to use the client method documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the `table` resource, you should refer to [this documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.update_item). For example, the `Key` parameter should have the following syntax:

```
Key={
    'string': 'string'|123|Binary(b'bytes')|True|None|set(['string'])|set([123])|set([Binary(b'bytes')])|[]|{}
}
```

This means that the DynamoDB data type is inferred from the Python data type. So instead of `{"N":"1"}`, you can use `1` directly. Here is a corrected version of your code snippet:

```py
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Visitors')

def lambda_handler (event, context):

    response = table.update_item(
        Key={
            "id": 1
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames = { 
            "#c": "Counters"
        },
        UpdateExpression= "set #c = :val",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ":val": 1
        }
    )
```

Comment: okay i copied yours and it worked I thought that at some point I put in the attribute values as they were like you did but I guess I made a mistake thank you so much

Comment: @Noahharris you are welcome. i'm glad i can help :)